# Where am I going wrong here? Keep getting the error "cannot add Foreign Key Constraint"

Tags: sql

```
Create table Emp 
(
     eid integer, 
     name varchar(100),
     age integer, 
     salary real, 
     Primary Key(eid)
);

Create table Dept 
(
     did integer,
     budget Real,
     managerid integer, 
     Primary Key(did)
);

Create table Works 
(
    eid integer,
    did integer, 
    pct_time integer, 
    Foreign key (eid) References Emp
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to mention what column it references.

Try:

```
...Foreign key (eid) References Emp (eid));
```